# Different heights of elements of subfloat

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I am using "subfloat" to visualize both an image and a table inside the same figure as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Summary statistics\label{subfig-1:tab}]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}\hline
            \textbf{Min.}           & 0      \\ \hline
            \textbf{1st Qu.}        & 0             \\ \hline
            \textbf{Median}         & 0         \\ \hline
            \textbf{Mean}           & 88.37  \\ \hline
            \textbf{3rd Qu.}        & 0         \\ \hline
            \textbf{Max.}           & 4356          \\ \hline
            \textbf{Std}        & 404.3     \\ \hline                
        \end{tabular}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[Histogram\label{subfig-2:histogram}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{capital_loss_histogram.pdf}
}
\caption{Summary statistics and histogram of the attribute capital-loss}
\label{fig:attribute_capital-loss}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the image is not displayed at the same level as the table, as in the following image:

[image: The problem]

How can I fix this?

Comment: use `[b]` on the `tabular`, as in `\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|r|}\hline`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Please, make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises because `\includegraphics` sets the bottom of the image along the baseline of the text, whereas, by default, the `tabular` environment puts the center of the table along the baseline.  This will make the tabular hang lower than the graphic.  The default alignment of the tabular can be changed with the optional argument `[b]`, which tells `LaTeX` to place the bottom of the table along the baseline, which is the same alignment as the graphic.  Here is the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Summary statistics\label{subfig-1:tab}]{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|r|}\hline
            \textbf{Min.}           & 0      \\ \hline
            \textbf{1st Qu.}        & 0             \\ \hline
            \textbf{Median}         & 0         \\ \hline
            \textbf{Mean}           & 88.37  \\ \hline
            \textbf{3rd Qu.}        & 0         \\ \hline
            \textbf{Max.}           & 4356          \\ \hline
            \textbf{Std}        & 404.3     \\ \hline                
        \end{tabular}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[Histogram\label{subfig-2:histogram}]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.60\textwidth]{capital_loss_histogram.pdf}
}
\caption{Summary statistics and histogram of the attribute capital-loss}
\label{fig:attribute_capital-loss}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly. Very good explanation!